# Hide launcher when switching workspaces

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

When I switch to another workspace, the launch bar on the left will automatically appear, this really annoys me.

How do I disable the automatic display of the launch bar after switching workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a Window maximized on the first workspace which causes the "dodge" hide of the Launcher be active. When you switch to the new workspace, there is no window causing the dodge behavior of the Launcher to kick in, so the Launcher shows itself.

There is no default way (in Ubuntu 11.04 -> 11.10) to change this. There are methods involving installing CCSM, yet these are unsupported and can break your Unity environment. I won't get into those, as I haven't tried them, perhaps others will.

What is good for you to know is, that in the upcoming 12.04 release you can choose to have the Launcher either always visible, or always hidden (on all workspaces), and you can adjust the size of the icons to reduce screen space used. Perhaps this will give you a working solution without resorting to hacks in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

MyUnity is a config utility that will let You do just that. 
MyUnity > Launcher > Behavior > Hidden instead of Avoid window.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use CCSM unless you know exactly what you are doing. I did not, and ended up having to reinstall Ubuntu 11.

The side bar alone made me switch to Xubuntu